# Issues with regex match using the =~ operator of the bash [[ command

Tags: bash, osx, regular-expression, date

On OSX, I am building a function to validate date formats and then convert them to epoch times.  The function should validate that the date is in one of the following formats, if not error:  `01/01/1970 10:00PM` or `10:00PM` (`%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p` or `%I:%M%p`)

**FUNCTION**

```
checkTIME () {
    local CONVERT_CHK_TIME="$1"
    if [[ "$CONVERT_CHK_TIME" =~ ^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9][0-9](AM|PM)$ ]]; then
        CONVERT_TIME="$(date -j -f "%I:%M%p" "$CONVERT_CHK_TIME" "+%s")"
    elif [[ "$CONVERT_CHK_TIME" =~ (0[0-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/\d{4}\s[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](AM|PM) ]]; then
        CONVERT_TIME="$(date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p" "$CONVERT_CHK_TIME" "+%s")"
    else
        echo "ERROR!"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

It currently works fine for `10:00PM` but is failing to match when I try `01/10/2017 10:00PM`

I'm calling it as follows:

```
./convert '01/10/2017 10:00PM'
...
...
+ [[ -n 01/10/2017 10:00PM ]]
+ checkTIME '01/10/2017 10:00PM'
+ local 'CONVERT_CHK_TIME=01/10/2017 10:00PM'
+ [[ 01/10/2017 10:00PM =~ ^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9][0-9](AM|PM)$ ]]
+ [[ 01/10/2017 10:00PM =~ (0[0-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/d{4}s[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](AM|PM) ]]
+ echo 'ERROR!'
ERROR!
+ exit 1
```

Thanks!

I've also tried the following regex:

```
(0[0-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/\d{4}\ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](AM|PM)
```

Comment: What are you expecting `d{4}s` or `\d{4}\s` to match? I don't think bash regex supports PCRE

Comment: `\d{4}` should match the year (four digit characters) and `\s` should match the white space

Comment: @steeldriver, that was the issue.  I modified the regex to: `(0[0-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\ [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9](AM|PM)` and it's working.  Write it up as an answer and I'll mark it.  TY!

Comment: What month (name) is "01/02/1970"?

Comment: Jan/02/1970...US date format :p

Comment: I'd check if osx date(1) exits with an error if a time string does not match the format. If so, I'd not do a regex check at all - leave it to date. You can try one conversion and if it fails, try the next. If that fails, exit with an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\d` matches a decimal digit in some versions of regex (perl), but does not in the *Extended Regular Expressions* used for the `=~` operator of the `[[` command in `bash`.

Therefore, change the `\d` to `[0-9]` for a pattern that will match 4 decimal digits.

Similarly for `\s`.  To match one literal space character, replace the `\s` with an escaped space (`\`).  If you want to match 1 or more *blanks* (spaces or tabs) then replace the `\s` with `[[:blank:]]+`.

## More importantly, to avoid these regex mix-ups:

`man bash` says that `=~` regular expressions match according to the *extended regular expression* syntax, as documented in `regex(3)`.
`man 3 regex` (POSIX regex functions) says `SEE ALSO regex(7)`.
`man 7 regex` gives a description of the regular expression syntax, and says `SEE ALSO POSIX.2, section 2.8 (Regular Expression Notation)`.

You can find the complete POSIX Extended Regular Expressions syntax described in  [*The Open Group's* Posix Regular Expressions documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

Comment: GNU grep's ERE and the local platform standard C library's ERE (as used by bash) are not necessarily the same thing. Safer to use the POSIX documentation at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04 to find the portable subset.

Comment: (GNU grep has some extensions that POSIX doesn't require such as `\<` and `\>`, and some platform libc implementations add `\s` and `\d`; if one wants to be portable, it's really best to write to the standard).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for pointing that out.  My error was assuming that `SEE ALSO grep(1)` in the regex(3) man page referred to GNU grep, instead of the POSIX grep.  I agree.  I always strive to write shell scripts to the POSIX standard.  Your comments have clarified some issues for me.  Thanks.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

One option if you have access to GNU `date` is to have that do the donkey work for you and avoid the RE complexity entirely:

```
checkTIME () {
    convert_time=$(date --date "$1" +'%s' 2>/dev/null)
    if [[ -z "$convert_time" ]]
    then
        echo 'ERROR!'
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

---

Since you've advised that you do not have access to GNU `date` and you need the RE to match for validation, you could use this approach. (I know you've several others that have been offered.)

```
[[ " $1 " =~ ^' '*([01]?[0-9]/[0123]?[0-9]/2[0-9][0-9][0-9])?' '+([01]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9][AP]M)?' '*$ ]]
```

I've added an extra space either side of the input parameter (`$1`) so that we can match any of *date*, *time*, or *date time* (with mandatory space between the two components). As written the date part demands a four-digit year in the 2000s; feel free to relax this requirement.

I've used `' '` to specify a space. You could use `[[:space:]]` to represent any whitespace if you preferred.

After the comparison has been made you can pick out the date component as `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` and the time component as `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm trying to have this remain compatible with osx.

Comment: @Jesse_b: OS X has [`date(1)`](https://ss64.com/osx/date.html) too although its options are different and you'll have to adapt the invocation a bit. Or you can install GNU date on OS X.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The link you provide does not show any alternative to GNU date's `--date` option.

Comment: @hvd: Oh, right. But [Apple’s manual page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) (linked at the bottom of my earlier link) does: `date -j [-f <input_format>] "$1" +%s` (if I'm reading this correctly)

Comment: @DavidFoerster, if you check the snippet of my script you will find that is exactly what I'm doing.  Converting the dates wasn't the issue, it was just validating them prior to conversion.

Comment: @Jesse_b I've added a variant on a suitable RE for you.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the \d and \s escapes don't work in your version of bash. Try using `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:space:]]` instead.

```
(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[[:digit:]]{4}[[:space:]](0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9][0-9](AM|PM)
```

In action:

```
bash-3.2$ [[ "01/10/2017 10:00PM" =~ (0[0-9]|1[0-2])/([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/[[:digit:]]{4}[[:space:]](0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-9][0-9](AM|PM) ]] && echo match
match
```

Comment: It's not actually the version of bash that matters, but the C library it was compiled against (which is where the regex calls are provided); thus, it's the OS it's being run on that makes the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This snippet on file s1:

```
mydate='01/10/2017 10:00PM'

pl " Expected output:"
cat expected-output1

pl " Results:"
# Linux: dateutils.dconv -f "%s%n" -i "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p" "$mydate"
dateconv -f "%s%n" -i "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p" "$mydate"
```

produces:

```
-----
 Expected output:
1484085600

-----
 Results:
1484085600
```

On a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Apple/BSD, Darwin 16.7.0, x86_64
Distribution        : macOS 10.12.6 (16G29), Sierra
bash GNU bash 3.2.57
```

The dateconv (aka dconv, dateutils.dconv) code is part of the dateutils package available via brew -- some details for dateconv:

```
dateconv - Convert DATE/TIMEs between calendrical systems.
Home    : http://www.fresse.org/dateutils
Path    : /usr/local/bin/dateconv
Version : - ( local: /usr/local/bin/dateconv, 2017-10-15 )
Type    : Mach-O64-bitexecutablex86_64 ...)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: What is `pl` here?

Comment: A function to print a header, along with "print like echo --                   pe":pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; } I have not always included them for brevity, but I am considering changing that stance.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: Yeah, please do. We expect scripts to be runnable, and we can't run this if we don't know what your `pl` command does. Ideally, you should just use standard tools to ensure portability.

Comment: I almost always attempt to run the code on a platform that is the same or similar to the questioner's if it has been provided. I usually develop answers on my workstation (Debian), then transfer to the user platform. If I cannot get it to work there then I don't usually post. If the user has not said what the platform is, then I stay on Debian. I try to use tools that are available in repositories, but some exceptions occur, like :align", and "cgrep". Our shop generalizes solutions when we can, usually preferring CLI options in code to complex awk/perl/shell scripts.  Thanks ... cheers,